# Set a background to run to the bottom of a page independent of page height

Tags: css

I want the gray background to continue all the way to the height of the current window. I tried setting height to 100% of #default-wrapper-body, but that doesn't appear to do anything.

See it live here: http://www.zorgbeurs.nl and even more prominent here: http://www.zorgbeurs.nl/aanmelden

I've also added an image, the areas in the right boxes should run to the bottom of the page, on all pages, not just the homepage.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the browser can't detect the height of the footer for one reason or another, also your not use a wrapper on all elements, a quick fix would be to add the following CSS to your stylesheet:

```
#footer_footnote_wrapper {
    height: 80px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
}
html, body {background:#f3f3f3;}
```

Comment: I added your suggestion, but on this page the background is still cut off: http://www.zorgbeurs.nl/aanmelden

Comment: Hi, I've updated my answer with adding a border and ensure that you use the html, body part too.

Comment: Hi thank you. When I do that a grey area is added below the footer. However, I want the entire center to be white and align the footer part to the bottom of the page. Like it's currently on the homepage. How to do that?

Comment: Then you need to add a wrapper that is 100% in height.

Comment: I added 100% height to #default-wrapper-body, but that does not fix the issue. Where should I nest this new 100% height wrapper and do I need to delete your existing suggestions from my CSS? Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
html, body, form, #default-wrapper-body { height: 100%; }
```

… does the trick, see here: http://codepen.io/zitrusfrisch/pen/ouEdI

Better move the form inside the #default-wrapper-body to prevent all forms being stretched to 100% height though.

Answer (score -1):

I think the cookiebar div is causing your white stripe at the bottom, it has background:none; and when its visible the background looks fine, all the way to the bottom.